# Hadoop 2.3.0 over windows 2008 r2 x64 about nodemanager

Tags: java, batch-file, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

everybody,
Recently I used Cygwin64, Maven, JDK1.7x64 and hadoop 2.3.0 Src to build package on Windows 2008 r2 x64,and it build success.
Finally I set all parameters of hdfs-site.xml,yarn-site.xml,core-site.xml and mapred-site.xml.

I go forward to format namenode and excute start-dfs.cmd,the namenode and datanode all work fine.
But when I excute start-yarn.cmd to start resourcemanager and nodemanager,only the resourcemanager works fine.
The nodemanager cmd window shows "The System cannot find the specific batch label - nodemanager"...

Please give me any possible suggestion.

Answer (score 7):

I replaced `LF` with `CRLF` in yarn.cmd in %HADOOP_HOME%\bin using and it worked for me (didn't even have to change to ANSI encoding).

Easiest way for me was to use Search->Replace (Ctrl+H) in Notepad++, set the search mode to extended, and replace `\n` with `\r\n`.

Comment: In Notepad++, you can go to `Edit -> EOL Conversion -> Windows Format`, then save the file and try again. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Open the yarn.cmd file from %HADOOP_HOME%\bin and save the file with ANSI encoding and also change line endings to windows (CR+LF) from unix (LF) using Notepad2. Then run the below command:

> %HADOOP_HOME%\sbin\start-yarn.cmd

It worked fine for me after changing the file encoding.

Comment: I did it as you said,but still got the same problem. I guess the difference is that my cmd window encoding is 950 ANSI /OEM:Big5. Finally I solved the problem by using "start yarn org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.Nodemanager" instead of "start nodemanager". I note here in case of the same situation from someone.

Answer (score 0):

Just rename Nodemanager to NodeManager.

Answer (score 0):

Copied from comment by @tanza9

In Notepad++, you can go to `Edit` -> `EOL Conversion` -> `Windows Format`, then save the file and try again.

[image]